# Injecting an Angular factory into another factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a factory injected into another factory.

The error is:

```
  `ReferenceError: testDataService is not defined`
```

I thought it should be pretty easy to solve, but it's giving me a headache. I seem to have issues with the various syntax involved in dependency injection.

In my main factory, I'm making the initial service call like this :

```
   this.treeGridOptions = gadgetInitService.initTreeGridTEST();
```

Good so far.

However, further below it blows up in `initTreeGridTEST`

Here's my testDataService factory, which just returns some hard-coded options:

```
 (function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('rage').factory('testDataService', [testData ]);

function testData() {
    var service = {
        treegridData: treegridData
    };
    return service;
}
function treegridData() {
    return {
        "altrows": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "columnsResize": true,
        "editable": true,
        "showToolbar": false,
        "width": "100%",
        "height": 400,
        "source": {}       
    };
}   
})();
```

and trying to inject 'testDataService' here:

```
 (function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('rage').factory('gadgetInitService', ['testDataService', gridHierarchyService]);

function gridHierarchyService(testDataService) {
    var service = {
        initTreeGrid: initTreeGrid,
        initColumnChart: initColumnChart,
        initTreeGridTEST: initTreeGridTEST
    }
    return service;
}
function initTreeGridTEST() {
    var myData = testDataService.treegridData();
    return myData;
}
})();
```

Your help appreciated,

Bob

Comment: `testDataService` is not defined in the scope of `initTreeGridTEST` it is just a variable defined in scope of `gridHierarchyService`. Just move `initTreeGridTEST` definision inside gridHierarchyService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testDataService` is just a variable in the scope of function `gridHierarchyService` and you are trying to access it outside the function where it is defined. Just move the function `initTreeGridTEST` inside the factory constructor and you should be good.

```
 (function () {
'use strict';

    angular.module('rage').factory('gadgetInitService',gridHierarchyService);

    //Just used it instead of array notation, i prefer this since this is more readable
    gridHierarchyService.$inject = ['testDataService'];

    function gridHierarchyService(testDataService) {
    //yeah keep service it in a variable incase you need to use service object for referring public functions as is. I am just returning it.
     return { 
        initTreeGrid: _initTreeGrid,
        initColumnChart: _initColumnChart,
        initTreeGridTEST: _initTreeGridTEST
     }

     function _initTreeGridTEST() {
       var myData = testDataService.treegridData();
       return myData;
     }

   }

})();
```

Comment: BINGO ! Thanks @PSL. I just moved the closing curly brace of gridHierarchyService() down to the bottom, just above `})();` .

Comment: a fellow New Jerseyan. Passaic county here.

Comment: Wow.. I am down south.. Middlesex county..  Cheers...:)